# Where/how to add completeness and other calcs in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add an additional calculation for completeness so that it works.
I.e : `SUM(cast(case when column is null then 0 else 1 end as float))/count(*)`

The query is meant to go through multiple tables in a database to profile the data.

Am not very familiar with dynamic query generation in SQL (I assume this is what it is).

Please see the code am referring to below:

```
-- I have removed the code before this as its just set up

-- Table variable to collect the final results

DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    [Schema] SYSNAME
  , [Catalog] SYSNAME
  , [Table Name] SYSNAME
  , [Table Type] VARCHAR(10)
  , [Column Name] SYSNAME
  , [Seq] INT
  , [Data Type] SYSNAME
  , [Avg Len/Val] NUMERIC
  , [Min Len/Val] NUMERIC
  , [Max Len/Val] NUMERIC
  , [Min Date] DATETIME
  , [Max Date] DATETIME
  , [Distinct Values] NUMERIC
  , [Num NULL] NUMERIC
  )


-- quote char

SET @q = ''''
SET @qq = @q + @q


-- The dynamic replacement strings for various data types

SET @stmtUnsup = 'null, null, null, null, null, null, 0'
SET @stmtString = 'avg(len([@@replace])), ' + 'min(len([@@replace])), ' + 'max(len([@@replace])), ' + 'null, null, count(distinct [@@replace]), ' + 'sum(case when [@@replace] is null then 1 else 0 end)'
SET @stmtNum = 'avg(CAST(isnull([@@replace], 0) AS FLOAT)), ' + 'min([@@replace]) AS [Min @@replace], ' + 'max([@@replace]) AS [Max @@replace], ' + 'null, null, count(distinct @@replace) AS [Dist Count @@replace], ' + 'sum(case when @@replace is null then 1 else 0 end) AS [Num Null @@replace]'
SET @stmtDate = 'null, null, null, min([@@replace]) AS [Min @@replace], ' + 'max([@@replace]) AS [Max @@replace], ' + 'count(distinct @@replace) AS [Dist Count @@replace], ' + 'sum(case when @@replace is null then 1 else 0 end) AS [Num Null @@replace]'
SET @stmtOther = 'null, null, null, null, null, count(distinct @@replace) AS [Dist Count @@replace], ' + 'sum(case when @@replace is null then 1 else 0 end) AS [Num Null @@replace]'


-- The cursor to read through the schema. 

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT 
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA
  , c.TABLE_CATALOG
  , c.TABLE_NAME
  , t.TABLE_TYPE
  , c.COLUMN_NAME
  , c.ORDINAL_POSITION
  , c.DATA_TYPE
  , c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  , c.NUMERIC_PRECISION
  , c.DATETIME_PRECISION
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
INNER JOIN 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
    ON 
          t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
      AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
          c.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('dbo')
      AND t.TABLE_TYPE NOT IN ('VIEW')
ORDER BY 
          c.TABLE_NAME
        , c.ORDINAL_POSITION


OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM TableCursor
INTO @Schema
   , @Catalog
   , @TableName
   , @TableType
   , @ColumnName
   , @OrdinalPosition
   , @DataType
   , @char
   , @num
   , @date

-- Process through the database schema

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @sql =
  CASE 
      WHEN @DataType = 'image'
        THEN @stmtUnsup
      WHEN @DataType = 'text'
        THEN @stmtUnsup
      WHEN @DataType = 'ntext'
        THEN @stmtUnsup
      WHEN @char IS NOT NULL
        THEN @stmtString
      WHEN @num IS NOT NULL
        THEN @stmtNum
      WHEN @date IS NOT NULL
        THEN @stmtDate
      ELSE @stmtOther
  END
  SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@@replace', @ColumnName)

  IF @sql <> ''
  BEGIN
    SET @Schema = @q + @Schema + @q
    SET @Catalog = @q + @Catalog + @q
    SET @TableName = @q + @TableName + @q
    SET @TableType = @q + @TableType + @q
    SET @ColumnName = @q + REPLACE(@ColumnName, @q, @qq) + @q
    SET @DataType = @q + @DataType + @q
   
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Schema + ', ' + @Catalog + ', ' + @TableName + ', ' + @TableType + ', ' + @ColumnName + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @OrdinalPosition) + ', ' + @DataType + ', ' + @sql + ' FROM [' + REPLACE(@TableName, '''', '') + ']'

    PRINT @sql

    INSERT INTO @Results
    EXECUTE (@sql)
  END

  FETCH NEXT
  FROM TableCursor
  INTO @Schema
     , @Catalog
     , @TableName
     , @TableType
     , @ColumnName
     , @OrdinalPosition
     , @DataType
     , @char
     , @num
     , @date
END

-- Clean-up

CLOSE TableCursor

DEALLOCATE TableCursor


-- Display the results

SELECT 
    [Schema]
  , [Catalog]
  , [Table Name]
  , CASE [Table Type]
      WHEN 'BASE TABLE'
        THEN 'TABLE'
      ELSE [Table Type]
      END AS 'Table Type'
  , [Column Name]
  , [Seq]
  , [Data Type]
  , [Avg Len/Val]
  , [Min Len/Val]
  , [Max Len/Val]
  , [Min Date]
  , [Max Date]
  , [Distinct Values]
  , [Num NULL]
FROM 
    @Results
ORDER BY 
    [Table Name]
  , [Seq]
  , [Column Name]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a query, include it in the question, not an off-site resource. The question should be complete on it's own; links can *compliment* the question, but they shouldn't be mandatory.

Comment: Though it *seems* like you want the percentage of rows that have a non-`NULL` value. Why not just `AVG(CASE WHEN SomeColumn IS NULL THEN 0. ELSE 1. END)`?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, but am stuck on where and how to place this in the query so that it works.

Comment: Without the query, I couldn't comment.

Comment: @Larnu code added

Comment: There are multiple statements in there.. Which one are you querying?

Comment: Since am not sure where in the multiple statements are the calculations being done before they get saved to a table variable, the place where I can add more calculations including the one in question, am not sure.

Comment: I think rather then giving the piece of code, list your requirement here so that the masters can suggest the solution. Going thru piece of code without knowing the requirement, wont help much.

Comment: Please ensure you provide a [mre] with emphasis on minimal - so cut down your code to the smallest query which illustrates the issue you are facing. Very few people here have the time to try and make sense of such complex code.